# Accessing python list in javascript as an array

Tags: javascript, python, flask

I have this in my flask views.py

```
    def showpage():
      ...
      test = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
      return render_template("sample.html",test=test)
```

I have this in my sample .html

```
    <script> var counts = {{test}}; </script>
```

This gives me a empty counts variable. How can I get the counts same as the test list in python?

Comment: Can you show rendered source with your template?

Comment: the thing is it doesn't render. if i use the solution below it says unexpected end of input at the JSON.parse

Comment: Is nothing empty string or `<script> var counts = ; </script>` or something else?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

1. When you insert variable to template `{{ test }}` it take object representation. For list of int `[1,2,3,4,5,6]` it will be rendered as `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`, so it is valid javascript array, but this method not safe complex objects without javascript-like representation, for example, test = [1,2,3,4,5,any] will rendered as `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, &lt;built-in function any&gt;]`, however this is just example and will never work.
2. To implicitly cast to javascript object in flask exist [`tojson`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/templating/#standard-filters) filter:

   ```
   <script> var counts = {{ test|tojson }}; </script>
   ```

   So if the object is JSON serializable, then all will be rendered, otherwise the template engine will raise an exception.
3. You also can send javascript code to your template:

   ```
   from flask import json
   return render_template("sample.html",test=json.dumps(test))
   ```

   but it is not a good approach and it's better use `tojson` filter that is also HTML markup safe.
4. I prefer to not mix any javascript code within templates and split templates, javascript and javascript data with ajax. If this approach is hard I would prefer to use `tojson` filter.

Comment: The `tojson` filter produces a **HTML safe** version of the value, `json.dumps()` does not. **Always** use `|tojson` in the template, not `json.dumps()`, when producing JavaScript values.

Answer (score 8):

You can also use

```
{{ test|safe }}
```

or

```
{{ test|tojson|safe }}
```

The `safe` filter is to be used within script tags.

Answer (score 7):

You use [json.dumps](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) in the flask view and [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) in the javascript code.

In the python view:

```
def showpage():
    ...
    test = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
    test = json.dumps(test)
    return render_template("sample.html",test=test)
```

In the JavaScript code:

```
<script> var counts = JSON.parse("{{ test }}"); </script>
```

Comment: This doesn't work! and it looks like JSON.parse(test} has mismatching braces?

Comment: the parse is returning undefined on the variable, do I need some extra filters here?

Comment: There are mistake, should be `<script> var counts = JSON.parse("{{ test }}"); </script>` and it not sense because `<script> var counts = {{ test }}; </script>` will have same result and more short for this example. No reason make json twice.

Comment: @tbicr Yup, overlooked that one. You are right. Updated. Thanks.

Comment: You don't need `JSON.parse()` at all; use `tojson` for a *HTML safe Javascript subset* instead.

Answer (score 1):

I've never liked having to use `json.dumps`.  In this solution, arrays are not a special case.  Just put your arrays and any other variable into an object:

**Python**

```
@app.route('/somePath')
def example():
    data = {
        'robotNames': ['Wall-E', 'Bender', 'Rosie']
    }
    return render_template('index.html', data=data)
```

**JavaScript**

```
<script>
    var flaskData = JSON.parse('{{data | tojson | safe}}');

    var robots = flaskData.robotNames;
    robots.forEach(function (robot) {
        console.log(robot);
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You try to return dictionary from your python showpage function like following and it will work:

```
def showpage():
    """Your logic for getting the list to return """
    test_dict = {"data_list": [1,2,3,4,5]}
    return render_template("sample.html", test=test_dict)
```