# How to use flask.jsonify and render a template in a flask route

Tags: python, json, flask

Is it possible to render a template and use `flask.jsonify` in the same route?

```
@app.route('/thankyou')
def thankyou():
    db = get_db()
    summary_cursor = db.execute('SELECT * FROM orders JOIN order_items USING (transaction_id) WHERE orders.transaction_id = (SELECT MAX(transaction_id) FROM orders)')
    summary = summary_cursor.fetchall()
    data = map(list, summary)
    print data
    return render_template('thankyou.html', summary = json.dumps(data))
```

Right now I am using `json.dumps` for serializing my data, but it does some weird stuff to it.  I would like to use `jsonify`, because when I do this I get a really pretty output that seems better to work with:

```
@app.route('/thankyou')
def thankyou():
    db = get_db()
    summary_cursor = db.execute('SELECT * FROM orders JOIN order_items USING (transaction_id) WHERE orders.transaction_id = (SELECT MAX(transaction_id) FROM orders)')
    summary = summary_cursor.fetchall()
    data = map(list, summary)
    print data
    return jsonify(summary = data)
```

Is there any way to combine the two?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. If you need return different response objects in one route for different cases: `render_template` return `unicode` that transform to valid `Response` and `jsonify` return already `Response` object, so you can use both in same route:

   ```
   @app.route('/thankyou')
   def thankyou():
       db = get_db()
       summary_cursor = db.execute('SELECT * FROM orders JOIN order_items USING (transaction_id) WHERE orders.transaction_id = (SELECT MAX(transaction_id) FROM orders)')
       summary = summary_cursor.fetchall()
       data = map(list, summary)
       print data
       if request.args['type'] == 'json':
           return jsonify(summary = data)
       else:
           return render_template('thankyou.html', summary=data))
   ```
2. If you need render json in template: you can use safe `tojson` filter in template. See my another answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23039331/880326.
3. If you need return json with rendered template values: you can implicitly render each template and set value for response dict or list, then just use jsonify.

Comment: Thank you for this. Could you explain option 3 a little further? I'm a bit confused by it.

Comment: For example you should have some json response: `{"status": "ok", "data": [{"name": "info", "content": "<div>INFO HTML CONTENT THERE</div>"}, {"name": "profile", "content": "<div>PROFILE HTML CONTENT THERE</div>"}, ...]}`. Each data item content generated with some template and arguments. So to create json response you can do something like this `return jsonify({'status': 'ok', 'data': [{'name': name, 'content': render_template(tmpl, **args)} for name, tmpl, args in db_cursor.fetchall()])`.

Comment: ahh okay, that makes sense.  i'm thinking that i will be going with option two.  thanks for the help.