# How to convert ObjectId to String in python?

Tags: javascript, python, json, serialization

I passed a result to javascript in json. But when I use `var myList = {{ pass_tmp|tojson|safe }}` to transform the result to json, there is a bug said that `TypeError: ObjectId('') is not JSON serializable`. I have read this question [TypeError: ObjectId('') is not JSON serializable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16586180/typeerror-objectid-is-not-json-serializable).But the situation in this question is a little different from mine.I have to convert this to json in a flask template instead of a python file.And I have to use the command `var myList = {{ pass_tmp|tojson|safe }}` to pass this from html to javascript.So I wonder if I can convert `ObjectId` to `String`?
Here is my Flask app code:

```
@app.route('/details/', methods=['GET'])
def details():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        mongoClient = pymongo.MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
        name = session['name']
        print name
        db = mongoClient[name]
        results = db[name].find()
        json_results= []
        for result in results:
            json_results.append(result)
        # json_tmp = toJson(json_results)
        return render_template('details.html', pass_tmp=json_results)
```

Here is my template(javascript) code:

```
 var myList = {{ pass_tmp|tojson|safe }}
        // Builds the HTML Table out of myList json data from Ivy restful service.
         function buildHtmlTable() {
             var columns = addAllColumnHeaders(myList);

             for (var i = 0 ; i < myList.length ; i++) {
                 var row$ = $('<tr/>');
                 for (var colIndex = 0 ; colIndex < columns.length ; colIndex++) {
                     var cellValue = myList[i][columns[colIndex]];

                     if (cellValue == null) { cellValue = ""; }

                     row$.append($('<td/>').html(cellValue));
                 }
                 $("#excelDataTable").append(row$);
             }
         }
```

So does anyone has any good suggestions to solve this problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23902596/how-to-use-flask-jsonify-and-render-a-template-in-a-flask-route Just try. I not confident.

Comment: I've solved this problem by just pass json to template~~~thank you for your help anyway

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem by just pass json to template instead of results.

```
   @app.route('/details/', methods=['GET'])
def details():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        mongoClient = pymongo.MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
        name = session['name']
        print name
        db = mongoClient[name]
        results = db[name].find()
        json_results= []
        for result in results:
            json_results.append(result)
        json_tmp = toJson(json_results)
        return render_template('details.html', pass_tmp=json_tmp)
```

And use this in template:
`var myList = {{ pass_tmp|safe }}` instead of `var myList = {{pass_tmp|tojson|safe}}`