# Going from Pandas Dataframe to Javascript Array

Tags: javascript, json, pandas

I need to create an array in an HTML file of the form:

```
<script>
   var markers = [
         [1, 2],
         [3, 4]
         ];
</script>
```

I can get this array from either one of two sources: python via pandas or sql. I know how to get the list into a flat file or json, but do not know how to get that list into the javascript array.

What's a good way to do this?

Comment: plz post your list, as an assumption you can `result = json.dumps(list)` from python end and `JSON.parse(result)` from javascript end.

Comment: I don't follow. if you can save the data to a flat file, what's the problem? Also, is this running via HTTP or locally?

Comment: Sorry, that is the problem. I can dump a flat file to a local server but then I don't know how to get the contents into the javascript array.  Running locally.

Comment: json is something like this:  `{"a":{"0":-64.08,"1":-64.09},"b":{"0":42.13,"1":42.12}}`

Comment: @racket99 kind of similar, don't know full match your case or not? have a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23038710/accessing-python-list-in-javascript-as-an-array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Django example, you do this:

view.py

```
data = df.to_dict(orient='records')
return render(request, 'XXX.html',{'data':data})`
```

in template:

```
data = {{ data|safe }};
```