# Import Python list of strings into Javascript script (HTML file)

Tags: javascript, python

I have an HTML file including an embedded script (Javascript). I need to import some lists from Python as variables and I'm having trouble with one that contains strings. To give an example, I have something like the following:

```
# In Python
list_of_floatnums = [2.5, 3.5, 4.5]
list_of_strings = ["January", "February", "March"]
```

Then in the script, I do something like this:

```
<!-- Embedded JS script -->
<script>
    var i = 0;
    var js_floatnums = JSON.parse('{{ list_of_floatnums }}');
    var js_strings = JSON.parse(['{{ list_of_strings }}']);
    for (i = 0; i < '{{ number_of_cycles }}'; i++) {
        // Do something
    }
</script>
```

However, I get nothing as output. If I skip the JSON.parse() for the string array:

```
var js_strings = ['{{ list_of_strings }}'];
```

Then I get everything else to work, except that array of strings (everything is assigned to the first element). For example:

```
In ["January", "February", "March"] you got 2.5 points.
In undefined you got 3.5 points.
In undefined you got 4.5 points.
```

Of course what I would require is:

```
In January you got 2.5 points.
In February you got 3.5 points.
In March you got 4.5 points.
```

Any clues on what I don't know and I'm doing wrong? I had always imported single variables with {{ variable }}, and that is straightforward.

EDIT:

1. I am using Flask.
2. number_of_cycles is an integer variable also imported from Python. number_of_cycles = 3 in this case.

Comment: what is `number_of_cycles` and please mention what you have write in // Do something

Comment: It looks like you have not eterate the value with loop from `list_of_strings` and you are only iterating it with `number_of_cycles`

Comment: What HTML templating engine are you using?

Comment: See this :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23038710/accessing-python-list-in-javascript-as-an-array

Comment: It should be like this `var js_floatnums=JSON.parse("{{ list_of_floatnums }}");` or `var js_floatnums= {{ list_of_floatnums |tojson }}`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing python list in javascript as an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23038710/accessing-python-list-in-javascript-as-an-array)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<script>
    var i = 0;
    var integer_value = parseInt('{{number_of_cycles}}')
    var js_floatnums= JSON.parse("{{ list_of_floatnums }}");
// or you can use var js_floatnums= { list_of_floatnums |tojson }};
    var js_strings =JSON.parse("{{ list_of_strings }}");
// or you can use var list_of_strings ={{ list_of_strings |tojson }}; 
    for (i = 0; i < integer_value ; i++) { 
        // Do something
    }
</script>
```

Actually, you can use one of these methods

```
var js_floatnums= { list_of_floatnums |tojson }};
var js_floatnums= { list_of_floatnums |tojson |safe}};
var js_floatnums=JSON.parse("{{ js_floatnums}}");
var js_floatnums=JSON.dumps("{{ js_floatnums}}");
```

Comment: If I try something like this:

    var js_floatnums= {{ list_of_floatnums |tojson }};

I get the following warnings:

    [js] Property assignment expected.
    [js] Declaration or statement expected.

And if I try to run the program, it crashes. It happens whenever I try to assign something without quotation marks "".

Comment: Sadly no. It works perfectly for float numbers, but the output keeps disappearing whenever I try to parse the strings.

Comment: @VicenteN Change it to `json.stringify` with the string.

Comment: `json.stringify` makes the rest of the output remain, but it doesn't give the string array as expected (i.e. it creates a string, not an array of strings). For example, `js_strings[0]` is equal to `"` instead of January, `js_strings[1]` is equal to `[` instead of February, and so on. (`js_strings = "[&#39;January&#39;, &#39;February&#39;, &#39;March&#39;]"`).

Comment: @VicenteN `JSON.parse` works fine what about pars `JSON.dumps`

Comment: I tried `json.dumps`in Python and it does almost the same. It converts to a single string, not to an array. According to documentation, Python lists should be converted to arrays, so it doesn't make any sense. Maybe I need to import something in addition to `json`?

Comment: @VicenteN In python try  to do the flowing :
`list_of_strings=json.dumps(list_of_strings)`

Comment: I've tried that as well. Not working either. I checked the Javascript Console and this is the error that it's been throwing: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token & in JSON at position 1`. And the data the script gets is `"[&#39;January&#39;, &#39;February&#39;, &#39;March&#39;]"`. So, I think it may be something related to the character encoding.

Comment: @VicenteN use `decodeURIComponent(list_of_strings)`