# My Chart.js graph output via Flask isn't showing the desired output

Tags: javascript, python, sqlite, flask, chart.js

I need to make a graph from the data in the ***SQLite database***. I am using ***Flask*** for this particular project. Basically, the table has a column named emotion which has the emotions - sad, happy, and neutral listed many times. I need to count the number of times these emotions are shown in the table and then make a graph with the emotions as labels and the number of times as the bars.

The below code is for extracting the number of duplicate values and append it to a list. The below code correctly appends the number of values in the list. As of now, the output shows a list with the values - ***[6,33,7]***

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
import sqlite3

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def graph_data():
    con = sqlite3.connect('gazemaster.db')
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute('SELECT COUNT(emotion) FROM GazeData GROUP BY emotion')
    values = []
    for row in cur.fetchall():
        values.append(row[0])

    return render_template("graph.html", values = values)

  
if __name__ == "__main__":  
    app.run(debug = True)
```

The code shown below is the HTML file that will show the output for the graph.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Graph Sample</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="barChart"></canvas>
    <script>
       var ctx = document.getElementById("barChart").getContext("2d");
       var lineChart = new Chart(ctx,{
           type:"bar",
           data:{
               labels: ['Happy','Sad','Neutral'],
            datasets:[{
                    label: "Emotion",
                    data: "{{ values | safe }}",
                    backgroundColor: ["#3e95cd", "#8e5ea2","#3cba9f"],
                }]
           },
       })  
    </script>  
</body>
</html>
```

However, the output shown is this -

[This is the output shown; it shows only one value when the list clearly is [6,33,7]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iwXFx.png)

What I noticed is, if I add more labels, the other values come up but that's not how I want it, as it leaves the other labels empty. Plus, it treats 33 as 3-3.

I feel like I am making a silly mistake but I can't point it out.

Comment: Are you sure your `values` variable contains the list [6,33,7] because it seems to draw fine with those values: https://jsfiddle.net/Leelenaleee/r6y0jozm/1/

Comment: It's an array, not text. Remove the quotes: `data: {{ values | safe }},` (also, always always always check the source (press Ctrl+U) to find out what is actually rendered, otherwise you're flying completely blind)

Comment: Please check this, you need modify list again. `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23038710/accessing-python-list-in-javascript-as-an-array'`

Comment: Yep, this is a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23038710/accessing-python-list-in-javascript-as-an-array

Comment: @LeeLenalee It was a mistake from my side, I assumed it to be a list when it was an array. Thanks for the clarification though.

Comment: @ChrisG You are right, that was a dumb move from my side. Removing the quotes worked and I'll keep the advice in mind. Thank you so much!